# XMLHttpRequest object reuse or new instance

Tags: ajax, dom, error-handling, javascript

I have this scenario that leads to "INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11" and I believe it's an architectural javascript problem:

I have to 'fire' four sequential ajax calls to some backend endpoints.

It's like:

```
oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

- a header set-up for the first request:

  `oXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CUSTOM-HEADER', '1');`
- a first synchronous open and send:

  `oXHR.open('POST', firstUrl, false)`
- the line above should be blocking for the next send that also has to change the header:

  `oXHR.setRequestHeader('X-ANOTHER-HEADER', '2');`

  `oXHR.open(method, secondUrl, true);`
- then another synchronous open and send, just like the first one:

  `oXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CUSTOM-HEADER', '1');`

  `oXHR.open('POST', firstUrl, false);`
- after the previous blocking request, the last async one:

  `oXHR.setRequestHeader('X-ANOTHERCUSTOM-HEADER', '7');`

  `oXHR.open(method, secondUrl, true);`

At the moment I'm using the same oXHR object;
Can you provide a feedback for a scalable architecture that would involve wrapping such sync/async requests?

Alex

Comment: You cannot set request headers before you have called `.open`

Answer (score 0):

you could try using some JS framework instead of native XMLHttpRequest object.  [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has quite handy ajax api

Comment: unfortunately I have to do it on my own, jQuery was exiled from our little project :)